# Concatenation of strings

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, formal-languages, combinatorics-on-words

We have two strings (i. e., finite tuples) $A$ and $B$.
We have to find if for some positive integers $n$ and $m$, the string $A$ concatenated $n$ times equals the string $B$ concatenated $m$ times or not.
I have made an interesting observation but am unable to prove it. It appears that this can happen if and only if $AB=BA$.

Comment: This is not string theory.  I reclassified it

Comment: I have a suspicion I've seen something like this problem before, and Jeffrey Shallit was the source. But I've been unable to find it by googling.

Comment: Particle Physicists do not have a monopoly on the English language. The question is about strings in the sense that Computer Scientists understand them. Let me just give a bit of friendly advice to the questioner: You have a conjecture: state it precisely, give some simple examples, work out the key steps that show that the conjecture is true for them and develop them into a proof.  There are famous books by Polya and Lakatos about this process.

Comment: Neither of the edits that Brendan and Boris made correct the logical imprecision in the question, namely how $n$ and $m$ are quantified.   However, getting this right is part of the exercise that is itself part of the training of a mathematician, so please leave the questioner to work on it him/herself.

Comment: @PaulTaylor The original tag was string-theory. One point of tagging is to attract the right people to the question, and moreover some people filter by tags. So it's a good idea to tag thoughtfully. Now, to the best of my knowledge, "string theory" refers to the physical theory, and computer scientists do not also refer to "string theory" as pertaining to free monoids (except maybe as a joke?).

Comment: @Paul Taylor: The description of our string-theory tag, http://mathoverflow.net/tags/string-theory/info , unambiguously refers to the physical theory. So, whether or not the term can denote in English something else, tagging an MO article as “string-theory” is only appropriate when the physicist’s meaning is intended.

Comment: user103260: We strongly discourage cross-posting questions on MathOverflow and [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Seeing that your questions were much better received on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/), we recommend that you keep asking there instead of MathOverflow.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question (and I also upvoted the question), since I find it to be interesting and despite the comments I find it to be on-topic. For a question like this, I would prefer that answerers post an actual mathematical argument, rather than simply a reference, which most people will not take the trouble to consult.

Comment: My blog http://bensteinberg.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/combinatorics-on-words/ gives proofs of this and related results.

Comment: The fact that Benjamin Steinberg wrote a blog post in large part about this very question establishes, in my opinion, that it is on-topic for MathOverflow.

Comment: Actually, this might be a good one for the old nuke question since it follows immediately from the fact that subgroups of free groups are free.  My blogpost actually was more concerned with the brilliant proof of the Fine-Wilf theorem by Shallit. I also proved the result if this question using a variation of Guba's proof in Sapir's book. There is a simple, but in unenlightening inductive proof. Anyway it is not something seen in typical math undergrad courses, but it is not deep.

Comment: The result follows from Corollary 1.2.6 of Chapter 1 in Lothaire's book [Combinatorics on Words](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eberstel/Lothaire/lo1.ps), which states that if there exists a nontrivial relation between two words $v$ and $w$, then both words are powers of the same word $u$.

Answer (score 6):

$A$ and $B$ can be considered as words in a free semigroup. Then $AB=BA$ iff $A=C^k,B=C^l$ for some $k,l$ and some word $C$. See G.Lallement, *Semigroups and combinatorial applications*, 1979, Chapter 11 Corollary 5.3.

Comment: Why couldn't you leave it as an exercise?

Comment: @Paul Taylor: Sorry, I don't understand your question :-(

Comment: Paul's comment means that this is so easy the OP should be able to work it out for himself.

Comment: No, I mean that the process of formulating the question precisely and working towards the proof is part of the training of a mathematician.

Comment: @ Paul Taylor: Are you sure that OP is a mathematician?

Comment: @Boris Novikov Yes, because any person interested in and reasonably literate in math. is a mathematician (like everyone who can manage to drive for 10 miles without hitting several animate or inanimate objects is a driver). However, I agree with your point that there is no reason to assume that somebody asking a question like this is a **professional** mathematician, so you were completely right to answer the question instead of telling how simple it was :-)

Comment: @PaulTaylor, it seems that you don't want to close the question, and yet you don't want people to answer it.

Comment: @fedja: Thank you = Спасибо. I also don't consider this site as a math olympiad.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to be answered by Theorem 1.5.3 of Allouche and Shallit's *Automatic Sequences: Theory, Applications, Generalizations* (Cambridge University Press, 2003).

> Let $x,y\in\Sigma^+$.  Then the following three conditions are equivalent:
>   (1) $xy=yx$.
>   (2) There exists integers $i,j>0$ such that $x^i=y^j$.
>   (3) There exist $z\in\Sigma^+$ and integers $k,l>0$ such that $x=z^k$ and $y=z^l$.

The book has a proof.

Comment: Here $\Sigma^+$ is the set of all non-empty words over an alphabet (a non-empty set of symbols) $\Sigma$.